# Flutter: cocoapods are not installing

Tags: ruby, flutter, cocoapods

i am running this command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

but getting this error

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    The last version of activesupport (>= 5.0, < 8) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 6.1.7.4. Try installing it with `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.4` and then running the current command again
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.
```

please help how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You need read the error you just posted very carefully

```
Try installing it with `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.4` and then running the current command again
```

and your Ruby version is need to update to 2.7.0 or higher

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

```
brew upgrade ruby
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a read here: [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)